# Java Map Adapter Equivalent in Python to use wsdl

Tags: java, python, api, dictionary, soap

I need to address the web service interface of another program. The API is provided in wsdl format and I have already implemented the integration via zeep. One function of the API, which is mandatory, requires a `MapAdapter` from Java, as passing parameter (in the XML Document "values"). My own program is written in Python. Has anyone had the same problem and has a solution?

Edit: XML Document of the API function:

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v23:write>
         <connection>
             <handle>?</handle>
         </connection>
         <channel>?</channel>
         <values>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <entries>
               <key>?</key>
               <value>?</value>
            </entries>
         <values>
      </v23:write>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it *"requires a MapAdapter from Java, as passing parameter"*? You are invoking a SOAP web service which expects an XML message. All you have to do is send it a properly structured XML request. You don't have to deal with anything Java in your Python code. Maybe edit your question to add more details about it and make it clear what the issue is.

Comment: I'm using zeep to include the wsdl file. Via zeep it's possible to access the methods of the API. So the method requires the Java class ```MapAdapter```. The API is ok with f.e. a Python dict, but behind the API, it only accepts this class.

Comment: zeep allows you to call the web service methods with Python code and Python data to send to those methods. Zeep then marshals all of that into XML form and transforms your Python method call into a SOAP call to the web service. There is no Java class. There might be on the web service side if the service is written in Java, but you don't care about that as the client invoking  the service from Python. I asked for more details because your question doesn't really make sense in the way SOAP web services work.

Comment: The web service code is written in Java, that's right. My question is a little bit complicated, because the API is only checking, if the object is iterable, so it's sending a positive response. 
In my opinion the error is behind the API, that the interface accesses functions if the `MapAdapter`and here the error occurs, which I cannot read out.

Comment: So what result are you getting? An error message? An empty result? How did you find out about the MapAdapter issue?

Comment: For short introduction: I try to write some data on a CAN-Bus system. The program behind the API is writting on this bus. The API itself send a positive response (the API only checks if the data is iterable). But if I'm analyzing the bus, there is no data on it. So the failure has to be after the API. The API documentation only says that the `MapAdapter`class is required as a parameter.

So in my opinion the failure must be in the function itself.

Because of this, I asked the question, if there is any equivalent to a Java MapAdapter available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the SOAP web service was really badly written, you don't need to worry about anything Java, even if the service is written in Java. So the web service method probably doesn't require a Java `MapAdapter` as a parameter and you don't need to look up a Python equivalent.

You are using a SOAP web service that receives XML requests and you already have a WSDL file. That should tell you the structure of the XML that you need to send, with what elements and of what types. Zeep reads the WSDL you passed in and allows you to call the SOAP web service like Python functions and sending in Python data.

Most likely, what's happening is that you are sending in some XML message that's isn't fully what the web service expects and the service does a bad job at dealing with it (you say the API itself sends a positive response although there is no data written on the CAN-Bus).

I suggest you remove your Python code from the equation and use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/) to troubleshoot the service call. Feed the WSDL to SoapUI and use it to generate request samples for the particular web service method you are calling. Fill in all the required details of the request and make calls with SoapUI until you get to see the expected result from the service.

Once you have done that, write your Python code using zeep to get the same request sent to the service from your code. You can [log the messages zeep sends](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html#historyplugin) to see what's going on while you do so.

*Hope this is useful. I can only provide a generic answer since you haven't provided many details in your question. Posting the WSDL would have helped, or a link to the web service documentation, to figure out what this mysterious MapAdapter parameter is.*

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot and may not provide more information. I already use SoapUi and if I enter the parameters correctly here, the API sends the data correctly. So you are definitly right in assuming that I am passing data to zeep incorrectly.
I'll try to post the XML document of the function, maybe you can help me with this again.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just needed to provide nested dicts.

`values = {'values': {'entries': {'key': 'TheKey', 'value': 'TheValue'}}}`

Inspecting the XML via SoapUi and your advice with the logs helped me.
Thanks for your support!